# Qt installation python BUG - linux (ubuntu)

Tags: qt, ubuntu

I tryed to install Qt5.9.3 and got this error:

```
sh: 1: python: not found
Project ERROR: Building QtQml requires Python.
```

Then, I check my python version.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/site.pyc
/usr/lib/python3.6/site.py
```

I tried to instal Qt5.9.8, and it gives the same error.

Comment: try with: `sudo apt-get install python python3`. How are you installing Qt ?, without this information it is almost impossible to help

Comment: python3 is already the newest version (3.6.7-1~18.04).

Comment: I have a makeQt file (https://github.com/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-2.1.x/blob/master/makeQt). In fact, I installed OpenFoam and now I need to install Qt to install Paraview...

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it seems that your environment variable PATH does not include the path to python . 
try to add it.